# How to make HTTPS request from mule ESB?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb, mulesoft

How to make HTTPS request without port from HTTP component ? I can't use url with port 443 or 80 because port number just appending with url and it says invalid url.
So how to make request just with URL instead of enter port number ?

Also, If i have IP address i can use IP + Port to access the data. but Server runs behind proxy server so no way to find application server IP.

Error Message:

Message               : Error sending HTTP request to https://xxx-yyy.com:443/rest/name
Payload               : {NullPayload}

### Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload

Root Exception stack trace:
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.NameResolvingRequestBuilder.nextResolvedAddresses(NameResolvingRequestBuilder.java:99)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.NameResolvingRequestBuilder.setUrl(NameResolvingRequestBuilder.java:75)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.createGrizzlyRequest(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:555)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.sendAndWait(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:355)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.send(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:303)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.grizzly.EEGrizzlyHttpClient.send(EEGrizzlyHttpClient.java:105)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:383)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:226)

Please advise.[image]

Comment: You have to specify the port. Using 443 is the convention for HTTPS if no explicit port is mentioned in the URL. You have to describe better the issue. What is the error you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the host name can not be found. That should be expected given that the host name is made up. You can find this error mentioned in this KB article: https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Error-sending-HTTP-request-with-java-util-NoSuchElementException

This error has nothing to do with HTTPS or the port used.

I have double checked that the host name is indeed not registered with nslookup:

```
c:\>nslookup xxx-yyy.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    xxx-yyy.com
Address:  121.14.27.78
```